# Ubuntu 20.04 : HDMI output not working Nvidia GT 620M

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, hdmi, ubuntu-20.04

On  afresh install Ubuntu 20.04 with the NVIDIA graphic card Geforce GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE], the HDMI output is not working and the driver seems not to be working.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DE9sv00001043sd00001477bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

There are two missing dependencies : xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390  and  ibnvidia-cfg1-390

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command failed on a fresh install for Ubuntu 20.04 with a

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

There were 2 missing dependencies : xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390  and  ibnvidia-cfg1-390

Installing both manually

```
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-cfg1-390
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390D
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

solved the issue. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 TLS (64 bit), it was working fine with 18.04 TLS on my DELL Laptop E6420.

Graphics: NVS 4200M/PCIe/SSE2 / NVS 4200M/PCIe/SSE2

after running below:

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

reboot the system

all good, HDMI is connecting to my HDTV

Comment: this worked for me, manual driver install unnecessary .

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above answers but they didn't work. Another way you could approach it is by uninstalling Nvidia then reinstalling it. You finalize by rebooting your computer. Here are the steps:

```html
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390      (you may need other version)
$ sudo reboot
```